# "chrome.exe" --single-process not working

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is creating multiple processes(chrome.exe as i can see in task manager) and it is slowing down my laptop. I tried modifying chrome shortcut as "\chrome.exe" -single-process according to the link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/og-xdL55RJM When trying to start this brings in a dialogue that "Google Chrome has stopped working". I checked whether windows online solution but it could not find any. I want chrome not to open multiple processes i.e. something like working with a single process. But not successful.

Just before posting this here i got to know the flag(--single-process) has been removed. But i want chrome not to spawn multiple processes.
Has anyone encountered this situtation please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could try using Chromium instead of Chrome. It looks like that flag is broken in recent builds,but they appear to be working to fix it. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477001

Comment: Same error with Chromium too.